# Sequence name and properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was recently watching a lecture on networks and noticed an interesting real number sequence there:
$$x_n = x_{n-1} + 1/x_{n-1}$$
with $x_0$ equal to some constant $c$. I started thinking about this sequence and figured out that:

1) I don't know how to represent $x_n$ as a function of $n$. Is this possible? If yes, what is the approach (or approach name) to finding such representations? If it is not representable as an explicit function, does it have a finite limit?

2) Does this sequence have a name that it can be googled by? What do people do when they need to search the internet for possibly known properties of sequences?

Comment: It obviously doesn't have a finit limit, otherwise it would satisfy
$$
x^* = x^* + \frac{1}{x^*}
$$
Here's a reference about your sequence http://oeis.org/A073833

Comment: @ikostia Fixed point theorem.

Comment: @uranix, you're right, the limit part is very easy. Did you just happen to know the oeis link or is it a well-known sequence?

Comment: I just generated a piece of the sequence and searched on that site

Comment: Also, that sequence is generated when Newton's method is applied as attempt to find root of 
$$
f(x) = C e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
$$